# My network manager Not working in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, network-manager

in my laptop i can't use wifi for problem in network manager. when i start laptop. it is connect to wifi,but after 4-5 minute it stop working every time. i reboot many time, install/reinstall network manager, some package libnl-route etc downgraded.  but still it not working properly. what can i do?
I'm using ubuntu 18.10